# Requirements file issue heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku

https://github.com/xNinjaRose/TCP-Chat-Room/blob/main/requirements.txt

I am trying to put my app on heroku, i found that you just put the modules in a file, but I see threading/socket have no version number, its not in pip freeze(yes its installed) and i try in the interpreter to find **version** and it says it has no attribute and deploy on heroku keeps failing saying it cant find threading even though my app runs fine local, what else can I do to have heroku accept my file

Comment: Both 'threading' and 'socket' are built-in to python.    Please include the errors that heroku is outputting.

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement threading (from -r /tmp/build_1f58826c/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)

       ERROR: No matching distribution found for threading (from -r /tmp/build_1f58826c/requirements.txt (line 1))

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. | and I tried w/o req.txt and it said it needed it

Comment: I'll have to defer to those who know about heroku; but my understanding is that since both ```threading``` and ```socket``` are built-in,  you don't need to include those in the requirements.txt.  But like I said, will defer to others.

Comment: I tried to just put an empty req.txt file, it deployed successfully, sadly the app needs an IP so wish i knew heroku didnt have IPs for applications, but thanks for the help! weird how u need an empty req't.txt file

Answer (score 0):

Answer was since this is default modules, just leave requirement.txt blank, which is weird its even needed if its empty but its solved thanks to a helpful commenter

EDIT: THIS IS STUPID, i want to ANSWER IT YET IT WONT ALLOW ME FOR 2 DAYS, it should be solved/closed